# Incremental Shrink on Animated Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a fixed, animated nav bar that shrinks on scroll.  Currently, it shrinks from 150 to 100 if the ypos > 10.

However, I would like to add a second stage to the shrink.  So if ypos > 10 but < 40, it executes state 1 and, if it is greater than 40 it executes state 2 which will be a shrink from 100 to 50.

Problem: I can get the first stage working, but I am not sure how to watch for the second state of the shrink or how to add the second class that changes the first.

```js
function shrink()
{
 ypos = window.pageYOffset;
 var topBar = document.getElementById("Top-Bar");
 
 if(ypos > 10 && ypos < 39)
 {
  topBar.classList.add("shrink");
 }
 else if(ypos > 40)
 {
  topBar.classList.add("secondShrink");
 }
 else
 {
  topBar.classList.remove("shrink");
  topBar.classList.add("secondShrink");
 }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", shrink)
```

```css
#Top-Bar
{
 height: 150px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #ccc;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 transition: all .2s ease;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 2;
}

#Top-Bar.shrink
{
 height: 100px;
 transition: all .2s ease;
}

#Top-Bar.shrink.secondShrink
{
 height: 50px;
}

.content
{
 content: "";
 height: 1200px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="Top-Bar">
<h1>Site Title</h1>
</div>

<div class="content"></div>
```

I am attempting to recreate the effect from the following page: http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/responsive-site-header

Comment: You're missing an `else`. The final condition - where you remove `shrink` and add `secondShrink` - is happening with every scroll of the page.

Comment: That's just a miscopy.  The structure of the code still won't work even  if that is there...that is why I am seeking help

Comment: Well, you should probably remedy it by editing your question, otherwise it'll be the first thing everyone points out. In its current form your snippet does absolutely nothing - at least with the `else`, it starts to animate.

Comment: Do you have a solution to my problem?

Comment: I can tell you what the issue is, sure. On the very first scroll of the page at yPos 0, you add `secondShrink` to the top bar. At *no point* do you ever remove it, so from here on out, the top bar will *always* have `.secondShrink`. Because of this, normal `.shrink` will never get hit.

Comment: In your opinion, what would be the best remedy?  A completely separate function for the second shrink? Or some type of trigger that notes when the first state has happened?

Comment: I'll submit an answer.

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments:

> On the very first scroll of the page at yPos 0, you add secondShrink to the top bar. At no point do you ever remove it, so from here on out, the top bar will always have .secondShrink. Because of this, normal .shrink will never get hit.

I've modified your code below so that only one shrink at a time is attached to the top bar. Additionally, your `if` and `if else` don't account for anything from `1-10`, or `39-40`. Conveniently enough, one mouse wheel click, or one down-arrow click is *exactly 40 pixels*.

Check out this cleaned up version:

```js
function shrink()
{
 ypos = window.pageYOffset;
 var topBar = document.getElementById("Top-Bar");
 
 if(ypos > 0 && ypos <= 40)
 {
                topBar.classList.remove("secondShrink");
  topBar.classList.add("shrink");
 }
 else if(ypos > 40)
 {
  topBar.classList.add("secondShrink");
 }
 else //ypos is 0
 {
  topBar.classList.remove("shrink");
  topBar.classList.remove("secondShrink");
 }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", shrink)
```

```css
#Top-Bar
{
 height: 150px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #ccc;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 transition: all .2s ease;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 2;
}

#Top-Bar.shrink
{
 height: 100px;
 transition: all .2s ease;
}

#Top-Bar.secondShrink
{
 height: 50px;
}

.content
{
 content: "";
 height: 1200px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="Top-Bar">
<h1>Site Title</h1>
</div>

<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Ah.  I understand what you mean now.  But one question, it still looks like one fluid transition, I'm trying to avoid that. If you check the link I provided, and do two separate turns of the scroll wheel, you will notice two very separate states of transition.

Comment: Unfortunately that effect would have to be achieved entirely differently. You'd either have to implement an algorithm to modify certain attributes based on scroll %, or just look for a plugin.